# Which lab value skeleton diagrams are used to display results for CBC, Chemistry, coagulation panel, etc?

Tags: blood-tests

Which lab value skeleton diagrams are used for discrete, cbc/cbcdiff, chem, and coag results?

[image]

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JonMarkPerry If you take a look at this [meta discussion](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/) you'll see that the focus here has changed and some things like the help section still need to be updated.  This question is a bit obscure and could use some editing, but it's not off topic.

Comment: That said, to the OP, could you please spell out  your question a bit more in plain language? You're talking to a wide audience.

Comment: @CareyGregory; which meta discussion? - your link just points to the meta site!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - Take a look at https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/962

Comment: @ChrisRogers; I still think this is a question for Biology.SE. It's not a question I would expect my GP to answer.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry But its a question you would expect a medical student / a clinician to know, and this is the site for them. It’s not a site so that you can ask your GP, but a site where medical professionals share knowledge. Yes, that means we overlap with human biology, naturally

Comment: @Narusan; okay, but doesn't 'overlap' mean 'is the same'? how does 'medical sciences' differ from 'biology'. and this would have been discussed during the original site formation process. probably not a question for here though.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I think you need to spend some time browsing the meta section and see the transformation that has been taking place. It's a beta site, and as such it's still evolving.

Comment: @CareyGregory; it's just that several questions exactly like this one have already been closed. i'll read the meta over the week.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I think questions that have been closed or migrated because they belong in Biology usually don't have much medical relevance. There's a lot of overlap but they're not the same.

Comment: @CareyGregory; like Stack Overflow vs. Super User?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yeah, that's not a bad analogy. SciMed is basically applied biology just as SuperUser is applied software.

Comment: @CareyGregory; then this question isn't really applied Biology in the sense that the Health proposal put forward. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048?phase=definition

Comment: A clinician or student would know what the skeletons are by the abbreviation, so OP is likely either early in their studies or not in the field. But it's a simple enough answer, and people may be interested in seeing how it's used, so I answered it.

Answer (score 5):

These skeleton diagrams are used as short hand to avoid having to write units and test names for lab values - you can just look at a diagram of numbers and know what they apply to.  Sodium is always in the same place, as is K, Cl, etc.

The skeletons are as follows:

- Na K Cl HCO3 BUN Cr Glu = Chemistry 7
- if you add AST ALT Alk Phos TBili Prot Ca = Chemistry 14 (which are usually in vertical form).

  - Your diagram has just the LFTs, which can be represented as in your diagram, or in others (it varies).
- PT PTT INR = coagulation panel
- pH PaCO2 PaO2 HCO3 SaO2 BE = ABG (Arterial Blood Gas)
- WBC Hgb Hct Plt = key components of CBC (Complete Blood Count) without diff.

I found this example of writing the CBC diff, but have never actually seen it written out like that.

[image]

Per request, [this is a Khan academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/health-and-medicine/lab-values/v/introduction-to-lab-values-and-normal-ranges) on lab values.  I couldn't find any formal resources on fishbone diagrams, they're kind of passed on in medical education...

Comment: Might be useful to mention that you'll see a few different shorthand diagrams for LFTs, but I've never seen a different way to diagram a CBC or chem 7

Comment: Are there any reputable references you can provide for background reading to what you have provided here?

Comment: That's tough because most of this is just passed down, but I found a video from Khan academy